# How can I select rows corresponding to the unique pair of column values with the highest value of another column in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

**My table looks like this:**

| A | B | X |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 | 3 |

### I need to select the row with the highest value in X column for each unique A, B pair.

**The result would be:**

| A | B | X |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 | 3 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (a, b) t.*
from t
order by a, b, x desc;
```

This allows you to select other columns from the rows, other than `a`, `b`, and `x`.

With an index on `(a, b, x desc)`, this would typically be the fastest solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `MAX` aggregate function as follows:

```
select A, B, MAX(X) AS X
  from YOUR_TABLE
group by A, B
```

Answer (score 0):

That would work like that:

```
select * from a where x = (select max(x) from a)
```